# How to find F and p-value in Linear Mixed models

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, lmer, p-value

I am still not very familiar with R and I would like to construct linear model of mixed effects using `lmer` function.
We have 3 independent variables with 2 modalities each time:

- group (G3 and G5)
- frequency (LF and HF)
- conditions (NR and PH)

and one dependent variable:

- Reaction Time (RT).

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zq9b0cp36hm1s3i/DataSample_Language.xlsx) is a sample of my data, extract of data `manipfreq`:

```
subject group   item    RT  frequency   condition
502 G3  ARGENT  677 HF  NR
502 G3  ACTION  814 HF  NR
502 G3  AFFAIRE 1278    HF  NR
502 G3  ARMOIRE 716 LF  PH
502 G3  AIGLE   761 LF  PH
503 G3  AFFAIRE 841 HF  PH
503 G3  ARGENT  919 HF  PH
503 G3  ACTION  1071    HF  PH
503 G3  AIGLE   1253    LF  NR
505 G3  ARGENT  785 HF  PH
505 G3  AFFAIRE 1028    HF  PH
505 G3  ACTION  1190    HF  PH
505 G3  AIGLE   1248    LF  NR
506 G3  ACTION  898 HF  NR
506 G3  AFFAIRE 1566    HF  NR
506 G3  ARGENT  2037    HF  NR
506 G3  AIGLE   707 LF  PH
506 G3  ARMOIRE 839 LF  PH
1530    G5  ACTION  705 HF  NR
1530    G5  ARGENT  755 HF  NR
1530    G5  AFFAIRE 789 HF  NR
1530    G5  AIGLE   481 LF  PH
1530    G5  ARMOIRE 495 LF  PH
1532    G5  ACTION  532 HF  NR
1532    G5  ARGENT  679 HF  NR
1532    G5  AFFAIRE 1142    HF  NR
1532    G5  ARMOIRE 423 LF  PH
1532    G5  AIGLE   484 LF  PH
1533    G5  ACTION  690 HF  PH
1533    G5  ARGENT  708 HF  PH
1533    G5  AFFAIRE 775 HF  PH
1533    G5  AIGLE   1027    LF  NR
1533    G5  ARMOIRE 1299    LF  NR
1539    G5  ARGENT  747 HF  NR
1539    G5  ACTION  771 HF  NR
1539    G5  AFFAIRE 827 HF  NR
1539    G5  ARMOIRE 518 LF  PH
1539    G5  AIGLE   566 LF  PH
```

What interests me in particular is:

- Main effects  of: “group”, “frequency”, “condition”
- Two way interactions  : “condition*group” and “condition*frequency”
- Three way interaction: “group*frequency*condition”

And also two way interaction “group*frequency” in only NR condition

I wrote a model that takes in account interaction between my IV and variability related to my subjects and items on the intercept and on the slope.
Here is my model (correct me if I’m wrong):

```
model=lmer(RT~frequency*condition*group+(1|subject)+(1|item)+(1+condition|subject)+(1+condition|item),data=manipfreq)
```

I need to find the F and p values.

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Have a look at the `lmerTest` package.

Comment: Read `help("pvalues")`.

Comment: You should not include `(1|subject)+(1|item)` in the model; they are redundant with `(1+condition|subject)+(1+condition|item)`